# Python search all files in subfolders containing specific subfolder name

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have 3 subfolders in the root directory and 2 subfolders in each subfolders, as shown below:

```
C:/main/canada/May 2022
C:/main/canada/Jun 2022
C:/main/usa/May 2022
C:/main/usa/Jun 2022
C:/main/mexico/May 2022
C:/main/mexico/Jun 2022
```

I am hoping to only scan for files in subfolders with name contains substring 'May'.

I am beginner and tried os, glob, pathlib, but don't think my thinking is correct.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 1):

You could try first globbing for subdirectories that match using `glob.glob`, and then finding their parents using `pathlib.Path.parent`:

```py
import glob
import pathlib
for subdir in glob.glob("C:/main/*/*May*"):
    print(pathlib.Path(subdir).parent)
```